# How to use a Promise to return this future value?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Simplified version of what I have:

```
const getAuthorizedConnection = () => {
    let myAuthorizedConnection;
    flowable.subscribe({
        onComplete: connection => {
            connection
                .authorize(
                    authorizedConnection => {
                        myAuthorizedConection = authorizedConnection;
                    }
                )
                .subscribe(
                    messageFromConnection => {
                        processMessage(messageFromConnection);
                    }
                );
        }
    });
    return myAuthorizedConnection;
}
```

It is clearly written incorrectly but I am not sure how to fix it. I think the correct way is to use a Promise in order to return authorizedConnection whenever it is ready and save it to a variable so that it can be re-used elsewhere to access the authorized connection. But I could not figure out how to compose this. Can anyone help?

Comment: See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) - you'll need a "new Promise"

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us more information on `flawable`? if `flawable.subscribe` is an observer and RxJS is a viable option, I would consider using something like switchMap to transform the `flowable` observable (and the returned connected) into the response from `.authorize`

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap